# PHP assigning variables

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
$start  = $this->getWeekRange($date);
$end    = $start->modify("+6 days");

echo $start->format("Y-m-d");
echo $end->format("Y-m-d"); 
exit();
```

OUTPUT:

```
2013-12-08
2013-12-08
```

it should be

```
2013-12-02
2013-12-08
```

why is that both $start and $end has the same value? even though I've already assigned the value on the $start variable before modifying it then assigning it to $end.

Comment: `var_dump($start, $end);`

Answer (score 2):

Objects are assigned by reference in PHP (and many other languages).

This means that `$end` and `$start` are pointing to the same object. In order to get a **clone** of that object you have to use `clone`:

```
$end = clone $start;
```

Now you have a seperate object in `$end` which has the same properties as `$start`; *until* you call methods or modify one of them.

For your example you should put the above line in the second line of your example and modify this line:

```
$end = $start->modify("+6 days");
```

to:

```
$end->modify("+6 days");
```

Comment: Yeah, I haven' t seen a diffrent way of doing this so far. Additionally using pure language approaches is always good.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$start  = $this->getWeekRange($date);
$end    = $start;
$end->modify("+6 days");

echo $start->format("Y-m-d");
echo $end->format("Y-m-d"); 
exit();
```